# Genomics Research vs. Genomic Research

Tags: disambiguation

Is it possible to draw a distinction between the two phrases?

There are a comparable number of Google hits for both.

I am also wondering about the correct use of similar phrases, e.g. memetics research vs. memetic reseach, economics research vs. economic research.